# Cheeger--Gromoll's splitting theorem with weaker assumptions on the geodesic

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Cheeger and Gromoll proved the well known splitting theorem:

> If $(M,g)$ is a complete manifold with $Ric\geq 0$ that contains a line, then $M$ splits isometrically as $M' \times \mathbb{R}$.

Here, *line* means that for any $R>0$, $\gamma|_{[-R,R]}$ has minimal length when compared to *any* geodesic with endpoints $\gamma(-R)$ and $\gamma(R)$.

What happens if we only assume that $\gamma$ is homotopically length minimizing?

In other words, assume that for any $R>0$, $\gamma|_{[-R,R]}$ has minimal length when compared to any geodesic with endpoints $\gamma(-R)$ and $\gamma(R)$ that is homotopic to $\gamma|_{[-R,R]}$ relative to the endpoints?

Is the splitting theorem still true under this weaker hypothesis? What if one replaces homotopy by homology? Isotopy? Essentially, I am asking for any counterexample or result where "line" is replaced by something more restrictive in the statement.

Comment: What about $M = S^1$?

Comment: Hmm, good point. Is there such an example where the universal cover of $(M,g)$ doesn't split?